# How to use node module in client code?

Tags: node.js

I've installed ReactJs module in my nodejs application, so React appeared in node_modules directory. But I can't use it in client javascript because there is no  reference.

So what is the best way to add such a reference ?
(Of course I can manually copy react.js script to scripts folder and add reference manually but it leads to code duplication and looks ugly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is the tool you are looking for. It takes Node modules and wraps them so you can `require()` them in client side JavaScript code.

### Example from [Browserify's readme](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

> Whip up a file, `main.js` with some `require()`s in it. You can use
>   relative paths like `'./foo.js'` and `'../lib/bar.js'` or module paths
>   like `'gamma'` that will search `node_modules/` using [node's module
>   lookup algorithm](https://github.com/substack/node-resolve).
>
> ```
> var foo = require('./foo.js');
> var bar = require('../lib/bar.js');
> var gamma = require('gamma');
>
> var elem = document.getElementById('result');
> var x = foo(100) + bar('baz');
> elem.textContent = gamma(x);
> ```
>
> Export functionality by assigning onto `module.exports` or `exports`:
>
> ```
> module.exports = function (n) { return n * 111 }
> ```
>
> Now just use the `browserify` command to build a bundle starting at
>   `main.js`:
>
> ```
> $ browserify main.js > bundle.js
> ```
>
> All of the modules that `main.js` needs are included in the
>   `bundle.js` from a recursive walk of the `require()` graph using
>   [required](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-required).
>
> To use this bundle, just toss a `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`
>   into your html!

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed answer. Do I have to call browserify every time I need client side script update ?

Comment: I mean If i change client side javascript. My guess was that bundle.js contains both client side and server side code so I have to recreate it when client side code changes

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you should only need to run a Browserify command when you update a something in `node_modules`, not when your other client side code is updated.